# Are these Self-Answering rules valid as of today?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-center, self-answer

While reading the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), I found this 2009 [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) containing the Self-Answering rules for Stack Overflow. I would like to confirm if these rules are valid as of today or if there have been any changes. I already attempted to search for them here with no success.

> No change in sort order. Normally, accepted answers are “docked” under
> the question. This is not true for owner accepted answers; they stay
> in standard sort order like any other answer.
>
> No reputation is earned. Normally, accepted answers confer +15 rep to
> the answerer and +2 to the owner. Owner accepted answers do not earn
> rep (or badges) for anyone.

Comment: Accepted answers [are no longer pinned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/786798).

Comment: No change in sort order is true for all answers now.

Comment: as the blog articles get older, they become more and more likely to be out of date; they don't get updated in the same way the help center does.

Comment: Since the community seems to agree that the text is outdated (first paragraph) and poorly worded (second paragraph) and should be fixed, I've taken the liberty of adding the "feature-request" tag.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> No change in sort order. Normally, accepted answers are “docked” under the question. This is not true for owner accepted answers; they stay in standard sort order like any other answer.

The behavior of self answers hasn't changed: a self accepted answer is never pinned. However, other accepted answers on this site are no longer pinned either. They used to be, and still are on other sites. Pinning is the default for sites; see which [Stack Exchange sites decided to unpin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369914/323179). (Not all sites have discussed it so the list is liable to change.)

> No reputation is earned. Normally, accepted answers confer +15 rep to the answerer and +2 to the owner. Owner accepted answers do not earn rep (or badges) for anyone.

This is poorly worded. You don't get the +2 or +15 from acceptance, but you will get reputation from upvotes (and lose it with downvotes). You can earn some badges on self answers, but not all. See the [detailed list of badges on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/323179).

Comment: I totally agree with the "poorly worded" part. Not that I felt confused but I am new here and could not find this specific information anywhere else.

Comment: There is a [help topic about self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)...

Comment: This badge can only be earned by self-answering: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner

Comment: @HereticMonkey my question specifically mentions I was reading that article, that's from where I got the link for 2009 blog post.